# i have a go to top button and i want to change its text and outline color to white when the background of button is dark so that its text is visible

Tags: css, sass, css-filters, mix-blend-mode

**HTML CODE**

```
<button
id="scroll-top"
(click)="scrollTop()"
style="background: url('scroll.svg') center 0px no-repeat"
>
Go to Top
</button>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#scroll-to-top {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: end;
position: fixed;
width: 90px;
height: 66px;
bottom: 50px;
right: 6px;
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .2s ease;
transform: translateY(100px);
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
color: green;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

I want to change the outline-color(when focus is on button) and text color of my button to white when the background is dark(i.e when background is having any color other than white).

I have tried using mix-blend-mode and filter properties but i am bit confused here.

**NOTE: i don't want to explicitly set the outline-color and text color as white rather it should be decided dynamically based on the background color of the button**

Comment: What exactly do you mean with focus? Do you want to change the style when you go over the button with your mouse? Because that would be called 'hover'.

Comment: we use tab button to focus on the elements right, that is the focus i am talking about

Comment: Okay, so the anwser I posted should work for you :)

Comment: @TRIIX you are explicitly setting the color, i want to set it based on background color

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button id="scroll-top" (click)="scrollTop()">
  Go to Top
  </button>

  


#scroll-top {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
/* align-items: end; */
/* position: fixed; */
width: 90px;
height: 66px;
/* bottom: 50px; */
right: 6px;
/* z-index: 999; */
/* opacity: 0; */
transition: all .2s ease;
/* transform: translateY(100px); */
/* border: none; */
cursor: pointer;
color: green;
font-size: 12px;
}


#scroll-top:hover{
border: 2px solid white;
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#scroll-to-top {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: end;
position: fixed;
width: 90px;
height: 66px;
bottom: 50px;
right: 6px;
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .2s ease;
transform: translateY(100px);
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
color: green;
font-size: 12px;
}

#scroll-to-top {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: end;
position: fixed;
width: 90px;
height: 66px;
bottom: 50px;
right: 6px;
z-index: 999;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .2s ease;
transform: translateY(100px);
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
color: green;
font-size: 12px;
}

#scroll-to-top:focus {
 color: white;
 background: white;
}
```

For the focus on the button you can use the [`:focus` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus?retiredLocale=de).
When you change the background of your page you can give your button another class to change its background.